# PRAGMA table_info not returning info of double quote escaped column name when tried on double quote escaped table name

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am having a table with its name escaped with double quotes ("Table")
It has a column which also escaped with double quotes ("03/06/17")

When I do table info pragma

```
table = "\"Table\"";
column = "\"03/06/17\"";
Cursor res = mDB.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info("+table+")",null);
int value = res.getColumnIndex(column);

if(value == -1)
{
    isExist = false;
}
```

it returns -1 always.

But when I perform normal query , I get the column.

```
    table = "\"Table\"";
    column = "03/06/17";
    Cursor cursor = mDB.query(table,null,
            null,null,null,null,null);
    int colIndex = 0;
    int colCount = cursor.getColumnCount();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(colCount-- != 0) {

        if(column.equals(cursor.getColumnName(colIndex)))
            return true;

        colIndex++;
    }
```

And the column was created using

```
    table = "\"Table\"";
    column = "\"03/06/17\"";
    final String DB_ADD_COLUMN_STATEMENT_TABLE_SHOP_NAME =
                "ALTER TABLE "+ table + " ADD COLUMN "+ column + " FLOAT";
    mDB.execSQL(DB_ADD_COLUMN_STATEMENT_TABLE_SHOP_NAME);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no column you specified in the data the `table_info` PRAGMA returns. Each row in the cursor represents a column from your table, please take a look at the example data, the `table_info` command returns for the table `create table one(id, field1, field2 text, field3 unique);`:

```
cid         name        type        notnull     dflt_value  pk        
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           id                      0                       0         
1           field1                  0                       0         
2           field2      text        0                       0         
3           field3                  0                       0
```

So if you are looking for details of a column with name `03/06/17`, you need to enumerate the cursor and check if its `name` value is equal to `03/06/17`